# What's the difference between "polynomial time Turing-reducible" and "polynomial time many-to-one reducible"?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time

The following definitions are from Li, M., & Vitányi, P. (1997). An introduction to Kolmogorov complexity and its applications (2nd ed.), pg. 38.

> A language $A$ is called *polynomial time Turing-reducible* to a language $B$, denoted as $A\leq_T^P B$, if given $B$ as an *oracle*, there is a deterministic Turing machine that accepts $A$ in polynomial time. That is, we can accept $A$ in polynomial time given answers to membership of $B$ for free.
>
> A language $A$ is called *polynomial time many-to-one reducible* to a language $B$, denoted as $A\leq_m^P B$, if there is a function $r$ that is a polynomial time computable, and for every $a$, $a\in A$ iff $r(a)\in B$. In both cases, if $B\in P$, then so is $A$.

Aren't the two definitions equivalent? What's the difference?

Comment: I think this question has been answered in any of the following questions: [1](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/types-of-reductions-and-associated-definitions-of-hardness), [2](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14278/mathsfco-text-np-and-cook-reductions), [3](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/problems-that-are-cook-reducible-to-a-problem-in-np-cap-co-np). Bottom line: The former allows multiple calls to the oracle, which gives you more power in a certain sense.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial-time many-one reduction is a polynomial Turing reduction that only calls the oracle once, and that returns the oracle's answer without any further computation.